# Jenkins Docker Compose: Volumes not mounting correctly in a docker compose executed from inside a jenkins container

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline

## Context

I'm trying to automate CI/CD with jenkins. I have a jenkins container (that its also an agent) that is connected to the host Docker daemon via volume in the Docker socket `/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`. The auth config its all done, and I can run commands like `docker run` and `docker ps` from inside the jenkins container.

## The problem

In one of the stages of the pipeline, after it executes `sh 'docker compose build'` succesfully, it has to execute `sh 'docker compose up -d'` an it does everything well until mounting some volumes. All the containers are created, but the ones tha mount a folder in the repo; for example:

```
volumes:
  ./conf/:/app/conf:ro
```

don't mount at all: it doesnt show errors but the folders (`/app/conf/`) that should have been mounted inside the containers are there, but empty.

In addition, the volumes that are mounted via other drivers or have no path, like:

```
volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static:
  prometheus_data:
  rx_images:
    driver_opts:
      type: cifs
      o: username=${SMB_USER},password=${SMB_PASS},uid=1000,gid=1000,vers=3.0,ro
      device: ${RX_PATJ}
```

Are mounted with no problem at all in the containers and can be reached and show all the files they should.

## Can't find a solution

I have checked, with `pwd` before executing the `up` command that we are in fact in the correct directory. I have check with `ls -lrat` that the `conf` its present in the repository before it executes the `up` command. The files have the correct permissions and just seem to not mount correctly in the newly created containers.

I have also noticed, that this folders I try to mount (actually called `models`, `conf` and `reference_images`) get "copied" to the `/var/jenkins_home/` of the **HOST** (wtf!) with the jenkins container having no permissions to that folder at all. Here is the jenkins container structure (done in a compose alone):

```
services:
  jenkins:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: jenkins
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
      - '50000:50000'
    volumes:
      - './jk_data/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home'
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
```

So I assume that is Docker the one that copies these files here, instead of mounting them in the containers they should be mounted in. But why? Is this some kind of bug? Or am I missing something? If its a bug, should I report somewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The issue stems from binding the docker.sock, causing all docker commands, including docker-compose, to be sent to the Docker daemon running on the host. Consequently, the path specified on the left in the docker-compose file, for the bind mount, refers to the host machine's filesystem, not the container where the docker-compose command was executed. This explains the creation of folders on the host machine.

To address this problem, consider two approaches:

1. Use a Specific Docker Image: Create a Docker image that already contains all necessary data. By pulling this image, you avoid specifying any bind mounts in the docker-compose file.
2. Create a Named Volume: Generate a named Docker volume on the host and use it in your containers. Modify your docker-compose file to utilize this volume instead of directly binding to the host filesystem.

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Following the question, the 1. The solution won't work for me, because the data is dynamic, but can work for others. 2. This is great if it does work. I will try it and accept your answer if it does. Also, do you know if with Docker I can connect to a remote dockerd, like in Kubernetes? If this is the case, I could just connect to the remote instead of using the socket binding, solving with this the problem. Thank you